# In text animation, after animate text color of white not fill properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a typography animation of the name "DESIGNER". After the animation, I want to fill it with white color but it's not working. So I just want to know where I am wrong.

For this, I have made the text in Figma. After that, I have copied it as SVG and paste it in HTML code snippet. then styled it and gave "stroke-dasharray" and "stroke-dashoffset" same as in console. And at last I have animate it by animation property.

My HTML code is as following-

```js
const logo = document.querySelectorAll('#logo path');

    for (let i = 0; i < logo.length; i++) {
        console.log(`Letter ${i} is ${logo[i].getTotalLength()}`);
    }
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(32, 35, 48);
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: fill 0.5s ease forwards 3.5s;
}

#logo path:nth-child(2) {
    stroke-dasharray: 571;
    stroke-dashoffset: 571;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards;
}
#logo path:nth-child(3) {
    stroke-dasharray: 463;
    stroke-dashoffset: 463;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 0.3s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(4) {
    stroke-dasharray: 493;
    stroke-dashoffset: 493;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 0.6s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(5) {
    stroke-dasharray: 226;
    stroke-dashoffset: 226;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards .9s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(6) {
    stroke-dasharray: 635;
    stroke-dashoffset: 635;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 1.2s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(7) {
    stroke-dasharray: 604;
    stroke-dashoffset: 604;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 1.5s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(8) {
    stroke-dasharray: 463;
    stroke-dashoffset: 463;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 1.8s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(9) {
    stroke-dasharray: 549;
    stroke-dashoffset: 549;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 2.1s;
}



@keyframes line-anim {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fill {
    from {
        fill: transparent;
    }

    to {
        fill: white;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    <svg id="logo" width="666" height="114" viewBox="0 0 666 114" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <mask id="path-1-outside-1_1_10" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0.0880127" y="0.335999" width="666" height="113"
            fill="black">
            <rect fill="white" x="0.0880127" y="0.335999" width="666" height="113" />
            <path
                d="M36.336 6.632C47.28 6.632 56.736 8.696 64.704 12.824C72.768 16.856 78.912 22.664 83.136 30.248C87.456 37.832 89.616 46.76 89.616 57.032C89.616 67.304 87.456 76.232 83.136 83.816C78.912 91.304 72.768 97.064 64.704 101.096C56.736 105.032 47.28 107 36.336 107H5.08801V6.632H36.336ZM36.336 96.2C49.296 96.2 59.184 92.792 66 85.976C72.816 79.064 76.224 69.416 76.224 57.032C76.224 44.552 72.768 34.808 65.856 27.8C59.04 20.792 49.2 17.288 36.336 17.288H18.192V96.2H36.336Z" />
            <path
                d="M120.005 17.288V50.84H156.581V61.64H120.005V96.2H160.901V107H106.901V6.488H160.901V17.288H120.005Z" />
            <path
                d="M212.553 108.008C205.929 108.008 199.977 106.856 194.697 104.552C189.513 102.152 185.433 98.888 182.457 94.76C179.481 90.536 177.945 85.688 177.849 80.216H191.817C192.297 84.92 194.217 88.904 197.577 92.168C201.033 95.336 206.025 96.92 212.553 96.92C218.793 96.92 223.689 95.384 227.241 92.312C230.889 89.144 232.713 85.112 232.713 80.216C232.713 76.376 231.657 73.256 229.545 70.856C227.433 68.456 224.793 66.632 221.625 65.384C218.457 64.136 214.185 62.792 208.809 61.352C202.185 59.624 196.857 57.896 192.825 56.168C188.889 54.44 185.481 51.752 182.601 48.104C179.817 44.36 178.425 39.368 178.425 33.128C178.425 27.656 179.817 22.808 182.601 18.584C185.385 14.36 189.273 11.096 194.265 8.792C199.353 6.488 205.161 5.336 211.689 5.336C221.097 5.336 228.777 7.688 234.729 12.392C240.777 17.096 244.185 23.336 244.953 31.112H230.553C230.073 27.272 228.057 23.912 224.505 21.032C220.953 18.056 216.249 16.568 210.393 16.568C204.921 16.568 200.457 18.008 197.001 20.888C193.545 23.672 191.817 27.608 191.817 32.696C191.817 36.344 192.825 39.32 194.841 41.624C196.953 43.928 199.497 45.704 202.473 46.952C205.545 48.104 209.817 49.448 215.289 50.984C221.913 52.808 227.241 54.632 231.273 56.456C235.305 58.184 238.761 60.92 241.641 64.664C244.521 68.312 245.961 73.304 245.961 79.64C245.961 84.536 244.665 89.144 242.073 93.464C239.481 97.784 235.641 101.288 230.553 103.976C225.465 106.664 219.465 108.008 212.553 108.008Z" />
            <path d="M278.348 6.632V107H265.244V6.632H278.348Z" />
            <path
                d="M376.714 35.72C373.93 29.864 369.898 25.352 364.618 22.184C359.338 18.92 353.194 17.288 346.186 17.288C339.178 17.288 332.842 18.92 327.178 22.184C321.61 25.352 317.194 29.96 313.93 36.008C310.762 41.96 309.178 48.872 309.178 56.744C309.178 64.616 310.762 71.528 313.93 77.48C317.194 83.432 321.61 88.04 327.178 91.304C332.842 94.472 339.178 96.056 346.186 96.056C355.978 96.056 364.042 93.128 370.378 87.272C376.714 81.416 380.41 73.496 381.466 63.512H341.434V52.856H395.434V62.936C394.666 71.192 392.074 78.776 387.658 85.688C383.242 92.504 377.434 97.928 370.234 101.96C363.034 105.896 355.018 107.864 346.186 107.864C336.874 107.864 328.378 105.704 320.698 101.384C313.018 96.968 306.922 90.872 302.41 83.096C297.994 75.32 295.786 66.536 295.786 56.744C295.786 46.952 297.994 38.168 302.41 30.392C306.922 22.52 313.018 16.424 320.698 12.104C328.378 7.688 336.874 5.48 346.186 5.48C356.842 5.48 366.25 8.12 374.41 13.4C382.666 18.68 388.666 26.12 392.41 35.72H376.714Z" />
            <path d="M491.672 107H478.568L425.864 27.08V107H412.76V6.488H425.864L478.568 86.264V6.488H491.672V107Z" />
            <path d="M527.114 17.288V50.84H563.69V61.64H527.114V96.2H568.01V107H514.01V6.488H568.01V17.288H527.114Z" />
            <path
                d="M640.686 107L616.782 65.96H600.942V107H587.838V6.632H620.238C627.822 6.632 634.206 7.928 639.39 10.52C644.67 13.112 648.606 16.616 651.198 21.032C653.79 25.448 655.086 30.488 655.086 36.152C655.086 43.064 653.07 49.16 649.038 54.44C645.102 59.72 639.15 63.224 631.182 64.952L656.382 107H640.686ZM600.942 55.448H620.238C627.342 55.448 632.67 53.72 636.222 50.264C639.774 46.712 641.55 42.008 641.55 36.152C641.55 30.2 639.774 25.592 636.222 22.328C632.766 19.064 627.438 17.432 620.238 17.432H600.942V55.448Z" />
        </mask>
        <path
            d="M36.336 6.632C47.28 6.632 56.736 8.696 64.704 12.824C72.768 16.856 78.912 22.664 83.136 30.248C87.456 37.832 89.616 46.76 89.616 57.032C89.616 67.304 87.456 76.232 83.136 83.816C78.912 91.304 72.768 97.064 64.704 101.096C56.736 105.032 47.28 107 36.336 107H5.08801V6.632H36.336ZM36.336 96.2C49.296 96.2 59.184 92.792 66 85.976C72.816 79.064 76.224 69.416 76.224 57.032C76.224 44.552 72.768 34.808 65.856 27.8C59.04 20.792 49.2 17.288 36.336 17.288H18.192V96.2H36.336Z"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
        <path d="M120.005 17.288V50.84H156.581V61.64H120.005V96.2H160.901V107H106.901V6.488H160.901V17.288H120.005Z"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
        <path
            d="M212.553 108.008C205.929 108.008 199.977 106.856 194.697 104.552C189.513 102.152 185.433 98.888 182.457 94.76C179.481 90.536 177.945 85.688 177.849 80.216H191.817C192.297 84.92 194.217 88.904 197.577 92.168C201.033 95.336 206.025 96.92 212.553 96.92C218.793 96.92 223.689 95.384 227.241 92.312C230.889 89.144 232.713 85.112 232.713 80.216C232.713 76.376 231.657 73.256 229.545 70.856C227.433 68.456 224.793 66.632 221.625 65.384C218.457 64.136 214.185 62.792 208.809 61.352C202.185 59.624 196.857 57.896 192.825 56.168C188.889 54.44 185.481 51.752 182.601 48.104C179.817 44.36 178.425 39.368 178.425 33.128C178.425 27.656 179.817 22.808 182.601 18.584C185.385 14.36 189.273 11.096 194.265 8.792C199.353 6.488 205.161 5.336 211.689 5.336C221.097 5.336 228.777 7.688 234.729 12.392C240.777 17.096 244.185 23.336 244.953 31.112H230.553C230.073 27.272 228.057 23.912 224.505 21.032C220.953 18.056 216.249 16.568 210.393 16.568C204.921 16.568 200.457 18.008 197.001 20.888C193.545 23.672 191.817 27.608 191.817 32.696C191.817 36.344 192.825 39.32 194.841 41.624C196.953 43.928 199.497 45.704 202.473 46.952C205.545 48.104 209.817 49.448 215.289 50.984C221.913 52.808 227.241 54.632 231.273 56.456C235.305 58.184 238.761 60.92 241.641 64.664C244.521 68.312 245.961 73.304 245.961 79.64C245.961 84.536 244.665 89.144 242.073 93.464C239.481 97.784 235.641 101.288 230.553 103.976C225.465 106.664 219.465 108.008 212.553 108.008Z"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
        <path d="M278.348 6.632V107H265.244V6.632H278.348Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="10"
            mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
        <path
            d="M376.714 35.72C373.93 29.864 369.898 25.352 364.618 22.184C359.338 18.92 353.194 17.288 346.186 17.288C339.178 17.288 332.842 18.92 327.178 22.184C321.61 25.352 317.194 29.96 313.93 36.008C310.762 41.96 309.178 48.872 309.178 56.744C309.178 64.616 310.762 71.528 313.93 77.48C317.194 83.432 321.61 88.04 327.178 91.304C332.842 94.472 339.178 96.056 346.186 96.056C355.978 96.056 364.042 93.128 370.378 87.272C376.714 81.416 380.41 73.496 381.466 63.512H341.434V52.856H395.434V62.936C394.666 71.192 392.074 78.776 387.658 85.688C383.242 92.504 377.434 97.928 370.234 101.96C363.034 105.896 355.018 107.864 346.186 107.864C336.874 107.864 328.378 105.704 320.698 101.384C313.018 96.968 306.922 90.872 302.41 83.096C297.994 75.32 295.786 66.536 295.786 56.744C295.786 46.952 297.994 38.168 302.41 30.392C306.922 22.52 313.018 16.424 320.698 12.104C328.378 7.688 336.874 5.48 346.186 5.48C356.842 5.48 366.25 8.12 374.41 13.4C382.666 18.68 388.666 26.12 392.41 35.72H376.714Z"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
        <path d="M491.672 107H478.568L425.864 27.08V107H412.76V6.488H425.864L478.568 86.264V6.488H491.672V107Z"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
        <path d="M527.114 17.288V50.84H563.69V61.64H527.114V96.2H568.01V107H514.01V6.488H568.01V17.288H527.114Z"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
        <path
            d="M640.686 107L616.782 65.96H600.942V107H587.838V6.632H620.238C627.822 6.632 634.206 7.928 639.39 10.52C644.67 13.112 648.606 16.616 651.198 21.032C653.79 25.448 655.086 30.488 655.086 36.152C655.086 43.064 653.07 49.16 649.038 54.44C645.102 59.72 639.15 63.224 631.182 64.952L656.382 107H640.686ZM600.942 55.448H620.238C627.342 55.448 632.67 53.72 636.222 50.264C639.774 46.712 641.55 42.008 641.55 36.152C641.55 30.2 639.774 25.592 636.222 22.328C632.766 19.064 627.438 17.432 620.238 17.432H600.942V55.448Z"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="10" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1_1_10)" />
    </svg>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this:

```css
@keyframes line-anim {
    50% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        fill: white;
    }
}
```

This fills in one letter at a time once the brush stroke effect is finished.